# Simple jQuery Hover Menu

Tags: jquery, hover, hide, slide

This looks really bloated, can it be rewritten any better/more compact:

```
$("#cart-summary").hover(
      function () {
        $('.flycart').slideDown('fast');
      }
   );
   $(".flycart").hover(
      function () {}, // mousein function not required
      function () { // hide menu on mouseout
        $('.flycart').slideUp('fast');
      }
   );
    $('.flycart a.close').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.flycart').hide();
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, compared to the accepted answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#cart-summary").mouseenter(function () {
    $('.flycart').slideDown('fast');
});

$(".flycart")
    .mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).slideUp('fast');
    })
    .find('a.close')
        .click(function(){
            $(this).parents('.flycart').hide();
        });
```

It's a small improvement, though. I couldn't guess the relationship between the `#cart-summary` and the `.flycart`s.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. However, you can do without the empty hover function: just use 
[`mouseenter()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseenter#fn) and [`mouseleave()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseleave#fn). `mouseover` and `mouseout` have subtle differences to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Look at the jQuery API for more info.

```
$("#cart-summary").mouseenter(function()
{
    $('.flycart').slideDown('fast');
});

$(".flycart").mouseleave(function()
{
    $(this).slideUp('fast');
});

$('.flycart a.close').click(function()
{
    $(this).parents('.flycart').hide();
});
```